# Why were a lot questions removed today?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

Today, a lot questions have been removed, decreasing my reputation.

[image]

What was the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These question have been [removed by the community bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006): They were older than 30 days, had no answer and a negative vote count.

Your edits for these questions gave you +2 per edit, but now they are gone too.

*Update:* See your suggested edits as a service for our community, not as something to make rep with. This [will stop soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) anyway. You have increased the probability to get answers for the asker for a while. The askers have seen they were not ignored, but someone tried to help at least a little bit.

That was not wasted time.

Comment: Hmpf, I dislike, though I understand. But thanks for the explanation!